# Удалить созданный элемент из DOM по истечении времени

Tags: jquery

Функция выводит сообщение. Через какое-то время сообщение закрывается, но остаётся в DOM. И при повторном вызове функции сообщения накапливаются и не удаляются. Как получить только что созданный объект и повесить на него функцию удаления через какое-то время?

Я генерирую для вывода рандомную строку и присваиваю выводу её как id. Но сзданные объекты почему-то не хотят remove(), если вызвать функцию несколько раз подряд (не дожидаясь завершения работы предыдущего вызова). Как быть?

```
function message(message_text, message_type='success') {

    id=random_string(); //личная функция

    html='<div id="'+id+'" class="alert alert-'+message_type+'">\n' +
        '  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>\n' +
        ' '+message_text+' ' +
        '</div>';

    jQuery('#message_box').prepend(html);

    if(message_type=='success') {
        $('#message_box #'+id).fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
            jQuery('#message_box #'+id).remove();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение переменной `id` перезаписывается последующими вызовами, так как ее область видимости шире, чем данная функция.

```
var id=random_string(); // var - to make id local variable!
```

Comment: там еще и с html та же проблема, просто повезло, что переменная сразу используется